# Dynamic form array validation Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular5

I am creating dynamic `FormGroup` and `FormArray` from the service response, Now I wanted to validate the form array if any one of the input has value else I don't want to validate.

```
this.billingForm = this._fb.group({
   itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
});

  initItemRows() {
    return this._fb.group({
      Id: '',
      orgName: '',
      billing: this._fb.array([]),
      payment: this._fb.array([])
    });
  }
```

Comment: which form array you want to validate?

Comment: billing and payment both array

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
// Subscribe to value changes on FormGroup
this._fb.valueChanges.subscribe(c => {
    // Check empty values
    if (this._fb.controls['Id'].value !== '' && this._fb.controls['orgName'].value !== '') {
        // Set validators
        this._fb.controls['billing'].validator = Validators.required; // You can specify any validator method here
        this._fb.controls['payment'].validator = Validators.required;
    } else {
        this._fb.controls['billing'].validator = null;
        this._fb.controls['payment'].validator = null;
    }
});
```

You can get more information on custom validators here: [Click!](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html#Building%20a%20custom%20validator)

Comment: you me to use this in constructor or in submit function

Comment: place this in you components constructor

Comment: But `_fb` is `FormBuilder`. shouldn't be `billingForm.valueChanges`?